# Check if there are any pending changes to be saved

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to find out whether there are unsaved changes in my entity context, in the Entity Framework?

Comment: Does context.savechanges() not automatically check this? Reason im asking is that I think a few people will try do the following:  `if (db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()) { await db.SaveChangesAsync(); }`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This might work (if by changes you mean added, removed and modified entities):

```
bool changesMade = (context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).Count() +
                    context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted).Count() +
                    context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified).Count()
                    ) > 0;
```

**Edit:**

Improved code:

```
bool changesMade = context.
                   ObjectStateManager.
                   GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | 
                                         EntityState.Deleted | 
                                         EntityState.Modified
                                        ).Any();
```

Comment: +1 for being generally on the right track, but use `Any()`, not `Count() > 0`.

Comment: Darn it - just read your blogpost regarding this today! Thanks ;)

Comment: Note that EF doesn't check if value is really different (for the `EntityState.Modified`). e.q. if you replace a value by itself, EF will returns `1 modified object`. You have to check beforehand if the value is different.

Answer (score 125):

Starting with EF 6, there is `context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()`.

Comment: Most up to date answer.

Comment: As of 2016 this is the answer, IMHO.

Comment: This is now the best answer as others have mentioned.

Comment: Neat solution! Thanks for sharing. Do you know how to catch changes on time and mark the modified form with " * " ? 
like: Form1*

Answer (score 46):

For those of you using EF 4+, here is an equivalent solution as an extension method:

```
public static class DbContextExtensions {
    public static Boolean HasPendingChanges(this DbContext context) {
        return context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                      .Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added
                             || e.State == EntityState.Deleted
                             || e.State == EntityState.Modified);
    }
}
```

Note that you can't combine the values as a bit mask. The function `GetObjectStateEntries()` handled the logic for you, but LINQ won't produce proper results.

Comment: Thanks, the accepted answer didn't work for me while yours did (EF v.4.3).

Comment: `EntityState` for `EntityState.Added` is from `System.Data.Entity` and not from `System.Data`.