# Get list of modified objects after Entity Framework Update

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

So I'm trying to prevent a race condition between applications.

Using IsolationLevel/TransactionScope, I can lock the table the way I need to, but need to run the update operation first, then operate on the list of modified objects.

To do this, I need to run the update and get the list of updated ID's all in one shot.

If I were to try to take the IDs first, that wouldn't lock the table, and another app instance could query for that same list, before they were flagged.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
//modify some objects    
var updatedIds = context.SaveChanges();
//Process updatedIds
```

Is there a way to do this? I've tried looking through the ObjectContext entries, but after the Save there doesn't seem to be anything.

Maybe I'll have to do an sproc?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131347/check-if-there-are-any-pending-changes-to-be-saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can go into your Context class and should give you what you need

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    using (var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
    {
        //pre processing
        var result = base.SaveChanges();
        //post processing
        scope.Complete();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up writing a SP that updates the rows and returns the IDs using OUTPUT, plus a transactionscope as written here.  thanks