# Getting the change state of a bindingsource,

Tags: c#

Imagine we have a binding source,which is populated by EF.

```
xxxbindingsource.datasource = db.stuff.tolist();
```

Then I set this bindingsource to a xtragrid;

Normally the dataset has .haschanged event for catching the changes,how can i achieve that in a bindingsource?What i want to do is,if user has uncomminted changes to the grid,i want to ask with a dialog whether he wants to save the data..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries`, (see this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Copying from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131347/check-if-there-are-any-pending-changes-to-be-saved) I give you an example...

```
bool changesMade = context.
                   ObjectStateManager.
                   GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | 
                                         EntityState.Deleted | 
                                         EntityState.Modified
                                        ).Any();
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: Cheers,bu for some reason, i cannot use this in EF 6.1, can not find ObjectStateManager in my context,any assemblies i should include?

Comment: Same here! Using 6.1 ObjectStateManager is not off my context