# WPF mvvm with entity framework: create save command

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, devexpress

*Assumpion: I'm a newbie in this world and I'm learning by doing.*

I have a menu on the top, with a set of button. Under this, I open various tabs, where I'm managing different data from my database, with entity framework (6.0).

In one of these tabs, I show my data, with a custom master/slave (list on the left, editable details on the right). How can I understand when user edit at least one value and enable the save button? And what have I to do to write the save command in my code?

**Considering I have a lot of classes in my EF model, is there a way to write only one save function for all these classes?**

Thanks to all will answer. :-)

Comment: have a look at `RelayCommand` in the mvvm light package

Comment: yep, RelayCommand + the check from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131347/check-if-there-are-any-pending-changes-to-be-saved in the canExecute method