# SaveChanges() and adding to DB not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, autofac

I am working on adding Entity Framework to our web app, asp.net MVC 5, but I am having a hardtime saving changes and adding to the database. I set up UnitOfWork with a generic BaseRepository, and I have tried a few things attempting to get this to work. first, I thought I could inject, with AutoFac, my repo in UnitOfWork like so

```
public UnitOfWork(IServiceItem serviceItem
        , ITechServiceItem techServiceItem
        , ITechnicianTime technicianTime
        , ISproc sproc
        , IRepairOrder repairOrder
        , ICustomer customer
         , IRepairOrderStatus repairOrderStatus
        , IRepairOrderUnit repairOrderUnit
        , IFiles files
        , IPartInventory partInventory
        , IRepairOrderItems repairOrderItems
        )
        {
            RepairOrderItems = repairOrderItems;
            PartInventory = partInventory;
            Files = files;
            RepairOrderUnit = repairOrderUnit;
            RepairOrderStatus = repairOrderStatus;
            RepairOrder = repairOrder;
            Customer = customer;
            Sproc = sproc;
            ServiceItem = serviceItem;
            TechServiceItem = techServiceItem;
            TechnicianTime = technicianTime;
        }
```

and my BaseRepo is like

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected DataDbContext _db;

       public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected DataDbContext _db;

        internal void GetData()
        {
            if (_db == null)
            {
                string accountNumber = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetCompanyAccountNumber();
                var connectionToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginSplitToken"];
                _db = new DataDbContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfConnString"].ConnectionString.Replace(connectionToken, accountNumber));
            }
        }

        public TEntity Get(int id)
        {
            return _db.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _db.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _db.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
        }

        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            _db.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }

        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            _db.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
        }

        public void Remove(TEntity entity)
        {
            _db.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            _db.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities);
        }

        public int CompleteData()
        {
            return _db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public TEntity Get(int id)
        {
            return _db.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _db.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _db.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
        }

        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            _db.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }

        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            _db.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
        }

        public void Remove(TEntity entity)
        {
            _db.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            _db.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities);
        }

        public int CompleteData()
        {
            return _db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

and my StartUp.Configuration

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

            // REGISTER DEPENDENCIES
            builder.RegisterType<EverLogicDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InstancePerRequest();
            builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.User).InstancePerRequest();
            builder.Register(c => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()).InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserStore>().As<IUserStore<EverLogicMamber, int>>()
                  .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(ISecurityOfWork), new SecurityOfWork(new SecurityDbContext())))
                .InstancePerRequest();

            //Database
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<SecurityOfWork>().As<ISecurityOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
            //Service
            builder.RegisterType<TechnicianTimeService>().As<ITechnicianTimeService>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<PartService>().As<IPartService>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<TechServiceItemService>().As<ITechServiceItemService>().InstancePerRequest();
            //Repo
            builder.RegisterType<Company>().As<ICompany>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<Views>().As<IViews>().InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterType<RepairOrderItems>().As<IRepairOrderItems>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<PartInventory>().As<IPartInventory>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<Files>().As<IFiles>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<TechDashboardService>().As<ITechDashboardService>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<RepairOrderUnit>().As<IRepairOrderUnit>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<RepairOrderStatus>().As<IRepairOrderStatus>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<Customer>().As<ICustomer>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<ServiceItem>().As<IServiceItem>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<RepairOrder>().As<IRepairOrder>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<Sproc>().As<ISproc>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<TechServiceItem>().As<ITechServiceItem>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<TechnicianTime>().As<ITechnicianTime>().InstancePerRequest();

            // REGISTER CONTROLLERS SO DEPENDENCIES ARE CONSTRUCTOR INJECTED
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
            builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();

            var container = builder.Build();

            // REPLACE THE MVC DEPENDENCY RESOLVER WITH AUTOFAC
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            app.UseAutofacMvc();
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
```

But with this set up, the database does not update or add new entitys.
Then i tryed removing Dependcy injection from UnitOfWork and set UnitOfWork up like

```
 protected DataDbContext _db;
      public UnitOfWork(DataDbContext context)
        {
            GetData();
            RepairOrderItems = new RepairOrderItems(_db);
            PartInventory = new PartInventory(_db);
            Files = new Files(_db);
            RepairOrderUnit = new RepairOrderUnit(_db);
            RepairOrderStatus = new RepairOrderStatus(_db);
            RepairOrder = new RepairOrder(_db);
            Customer = new Customer(_db);
            Sproc = new Sproc(_db);
            ServiceItem = new ServiceItem(_db);
            TechServiceItem = new TechServiceItem(_db);
            TechnicianTime = new TechnicianTime(_db);
        }
  internal void GetData()
        {
            if (_db == null)
            {
                string accountNumber = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetCompanyAccountNumber();
                var connectionToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginSplitToken"];
                _db = new DataDbContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfConnString"].ConnectionString.Replace(connectionToken, accountNumber));
            }
        }
```

and moving SaveChanges from the BaseRepo to UnitOfWork, but still nothing is saving or adding to the database. 
What am i missing????

Comment: When you call `SaveChanges`, what happens? Any error messages? Next, before you call this method, what's the status of the `_db.ChangeTracker` `HasChanges()` or `Entries`?

Comment: Perhaps you could start _without_ wrapping the DbContext in extra unit of work and repository abstractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*TL;DR* the problem is that all your repositories are using separate, independent `DbContexts`, so the `DbContext` injected into your `UnitOfWork` has no pending changes when you call `SaveChanges` on it, so that's why you aren't seeing any change to the database.

In order for the Unit of Work to function correctly, your `UnitOfWork` class, and all the repository classes which your code needs to perform data persistence, must all share the same `DbContext` instance. In your code, it's clear that each repository has a factory method to create it's own, independent `DbContext` instance.

- Remove the `GetData()` factory method from your `BaseRepository` class, and instead, require an instance of your `EverLogicDbContext` instance to injected to the constructor of `BaseRepository` by AutoFac. This will require that all your Repository subclasses also need to have a constructor accepting this same `EverLogicDbContext`.
- As per your last edit, the `UnitOfWork` class must accept the same, shared `EverLogicDbContext` that the repositories use. Since you've tagged with `asp.net-mvc` then `RequestPerInstance` lifetime scope is correct for your scenario.
- Your `UnitOfWork` class needs to control the `SaveChanges(Async)` method, so remove the `CompleteData` method from the `BaseRepository` class.
- As you already seem to have done, the `DbContext` needs to be registered `InstancePerRequest`:

```
builder.RegisterType<EverLogicDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
```

If all this is tied together correctly:

- AutoFac will create an instance of your concrete `DbContext` the first time it is needed during processing of each Request.
- All Repositories will then share the same `DbContext` instance for the lifetime of the Request, and the DbContext will track interim changes made by your services.
- The `UnitOfWork` injected into your main "business logic" (e.g. Controller, or Orchestrator / Handler) will then be able to `Commit` the actions taken by simply calling `SaveChangesAsync` on the shared `DbContext`. This will all happen under a single database connection, so will be a lightweight transaction.

As per other comments above, IMO Entity Framework is a already high level framework with transactional support built-in, so there's little point in over-engineering a "UnitOfWork" pattern if all the ACID activity will be conducted against the same Database (and can be wrapped into the same DbContext).

Comment: Well, I am not using the same database. Every user is attached to a company and every company has its own database, plus an additional database to track data not related to the company and login info.
That is why I have GetData() creating the connection string, because i need to know what database i am connecting to

Comment: I guess it would have been clearer to indicate that your repositories span multiple databases (you mentioned `adding to the database`)
For multiple Dbs, the same principal applies, IoC creates an instance per Db per Request, and you'll need to inject all the **shared** DbContexts (used in the repositories) into your `UnitOfWork` class. You'll also want to track whether each DbContext has pending changes (See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26257585). But to be truly transactional, you'll need to rope in something like `TransactionScope` and enable DTC or XA on your databases.